# Get res object in nodejs custom module

Tags: node.js

I am generating a helper custom module, that should return **res.status(422).json(objError)**. But how do I get the res object?
I tried using including express library in that module nothing changes.

**nodejs custom module**

```
function Validation(result){
    if(result.error){
        //422 Validation Error
        var objError = [];    
        Object.keys(result.error.details).forEach(function(key) {
            objError.push(result.error.details[key]['message']);
        });
        return res.status(422).json(objError);
    }
}

module.exports.JV = Validation
```

Comment: `res` is not a global object that you will get directly in the function. You will get the `req` and `res` object as parameters in the callback function of `express.get()` or other related express functions. Refer example in the [link](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass response object into the function.

```
function validateAndResponse(result, res){
    if(result.error){
        //422 Validation Error
        var objError = [];    
        Object.keys(result.error.details).forEach(function(key) {
            objError.push(result.error.details[key]['message']);
        });
        return res.status(422).json(objError);
    }
}
```

Then call as: validateAndResponse(result, res);

Idealy, you should not do this in your function to keep SingleResponsiblity of the function.

Comment: why shold not? i am refactoring code, please give me proper reason so that i dont do that.

Comment: If you use `res` in a different module, it just isn't as obvious what your route does anymore. One would need to look at your helper module.

Comment: If you'd implement it as a middleware function, that would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can send res as an argument in your method

```
function Validation(result, res){
if(result.error){
    //422 Validation Error
    var objError = [];    
    Object.keys(result.error.details).forEach(function(key) {
        objError.push(result.error.details[key]['message']);
    });
    return res.status(422).json(objError);
}
```

}

this should work